# Debugging of Asp Net Pages very slow.

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis

In my computer IIS takes a long time (sometimes 10 secs) to load the first page of my web site. After that it seems to be responsive enough.
Is it because I am debugging?
What solutions do exist to reduce the loading time of the site?

Comment: NB: You've asked seven questions in the last two days, which is rather a lot, which IMO is a rate that may be indicative of not doing much research on your problems. Two look like they are about to close (one of which is lacking an [mcve] and the other looks too broad). You may find that doing more research is in your own interests, as too many closed questions can result in an automatic question ban.

Comment: Many things can have impact on debugging performance, your hard disk type, antivirus, Visual Studio version, and how complex the site is. Thus, 10 seconds can be supernatural if it is required. Do learn how to do performance profiling, using a performance profiler (Google can tell you much), and then you might figure out the actual cause.